# blockchain.info api_code is missing

Tags: php, bitcoin, blockchain

I use php api for blockchain.info.

here is my code:

```
$Blockchain = new \Blockchain\Blockchain();
$Blockchain->setServiceUrl('http://localhost:' . env('BTCPORT') . '/');
$Blockchain->Wallet->credentials($w_id, $w_password);
// $w_id is wallet id
$response = $Blockchain->Wallet->send($account, $amount, null, $fee, 'my comment');
```

And here my node.js process says 'error: Missing query parameter: api_code'.
I use this php library https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the blockchain api. it should be

```
$Blockchain = new \Blockchain\Blockchain($url, $my_api_code);
```

If you need an API code, you can get [here](https://blockchain.info/api/api_create_code).